# Rule based display labels, show different value with first is null

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am attempting to create a mapping system for navigation at my small fire department using QGIS and a GPS.  I am attempting to show spaces in a trailer park or apartment building instead of the street address.  So instead of the label 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, over and over, it would read (space: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5) Some of these are very close together so I was hoping that if value "space Number" is present then value "address" is absent.  Also, if there is no space number it would just read the address.

I attempted the "ADDRESS || '\n' || SPACE" and when I do so it only shows the labels that have both values.  I just want one or the other, how could I write that expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of putting the whole condition into one expression, you can also create two, to handle the two cases separately.
See the following screenshot for details:
[image]

By using this rules, the value from the column "space" is used as a label, if a value exists. Otherwise it shows the "address" value of the feature.